# Associative rules in a two-element set

Tags: abstract-algebra

In one of the exercises in *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Pinter, we are asked to find which of the sixteen possible operations on the set $\{a,b\}$ are associative. (I hope it's clear; otherwise, please let me know and I'll post a detailed explanation.)

Two me it appears that, since associativity is defined for three (or more?) elements, none of the possible operations is associative. However, on other thoughts, since the whole idea of associativity is absurb in a two-element set, one might as well assume that all the elements are associative.

I doubt if the second argument is worthwhile at all, but would love to have some light shed on this.

Comment: Associativity is defined for triples of elements, but these elements are not required to be distinct. So there is actually something to check for each of these sixteen possible operations.

Comment: Ah, the same way that commutativity can be checked on a single element! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering myself so as to close this question)
As explained in a comment above, "Associativity is defined for triples of elements, but these elements are not required to be distinct."